# Django keeps referring to the local database instead of the remote database

Tags: django, postgresql, remote-server

I've recently migrated my postgresql database to a remote server. It used to be on the same machine where I ran Django. I decided to make the move to lighten the load on the machine.

I ran into some trouble however. I did a syncdb and the tables synced up the remote database. I checked to see if the tables did indeed sync and they we're there. Inside the tables there is no data, I have yet to populate them. However, when I access the Django admin page, it's somehow populated with the old data from the local database.

I find this behavior extremely strange. I decided to delete the local database and I got the following error:

```
FATAL:  database "django_db" does not exist
```

This is weird because the tables are all on the remote database. Both the local and the remote database are called django_db. Could that be the problem?

This is what I have in my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'django_db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'django_login',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'password',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': 'XX.XXX.X.XX',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
},
}
```

Comment: How have you told Django where the database is?

Comment: can you show your database settings ?

Comment: What's in your configuration file? Can you copy the corresponding sections verbatimly, or better post the whole file, eg. on Gist?

Comment: @DanielRoseman please take a look at the question again, I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I actually had to restart the server that I was working on. It seems, restarting the HTTP server alone won't do that job. The previously compiled code, the .pyc files will linger around unless the server is restarted!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your settings.py file to point to your new database.  This is controlled by the `DATABASES` dictionary.  Also, as an added tip, I would recommend that you update your system and use [dj_database_url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url)

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}
```

This will keep your database password out of version control.  You then just need to create an ENV VAR named DATABASE_URL that contains the information to for your new database.  See the documentation or google for more information.